# How to find d, given p, q, and e in RSA?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I know I need to use the [extended euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), but I'm not sure exactly what calculations I need to do. I have huge numbers. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to hack RSA? If this is the goal, then currently there is no known algorithms that can do it in reasonable time. And this is kind of the point of RSA in the first place.

Comment: No. I know I have enough information to solve for d, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422633/rsa-private-key-calculation-with-extended-euclidean-algorithm?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915383/bigintegers-gcd-modulus-inverse-to-find-public-key

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSA private exponent determination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316453/rsa-private-exponent-determination)

Comment: I've already gone through those. I just need to know what math formulas to do.

Comment: @zespri The OP clearly stated that they have know the prime factors of the modulus. So it doesn't require breaking RSA.

Comment: @CodesInChaos it's a moot point now, we have already clarified that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, `d` is chosen such that `d * e == 1 modulo (p-1)(q-1)`, so you could use the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) for that ([finding the modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)).

If you are not interested in understanding the algorithm, you can just call [BigInteger#modInverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modInverse%28java.math.BigInteger%29) directly.

```
 d = e.modInverse(p_1.multiply(q_1))
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure just how to use the Euclidean algorithm. Would be awesome if you could help. Thanks.

Comment: @user1816690 what part of the algorithm do you need help with? What is your specific problem?

Comment: I have huge numbers, but I'll explain what I have. I have the variables q, p, e and c. I want do find d. What math do I need to do to find d?

Comment: @user1816690 you need to apply (extended) Euclidean algorithm as Thilo says in his answer.

Comment: Yeah, i get that. The problem I'm having is how do I use that algorithm for this.

Comment: For the huge numbers, you need to use the BigInteger class in Java.

Comment: I understand that too. I don't understand what variables to plug into the algorithm, and how to calculate the algorithm.

Comment: Basically what I'm asking is, in the forumla for the EEA(ax+bx = gcd(a,b), what are a and b

Comment: The best solution I've seen. Thanks for such a simple and straight forward answer.

Answer (score 26):

Given that, p=11, q=7, e =17, n=77, φ (n) = 60 and d=?

First substitute values from the formula:-

ed mod φ (n) =1

17 d mod 60 = 1

The next step: – take the totient of n, which is 60 to your left hand side and [e] to your right hand side.

60           =             17

3rd step: – ask how many times 17 goes to 60. That is 3.5….. Ignore the remainder and take 3.

60           =             3(17)

Step 4: – now you need to balance this equation  60    =             3(17) such that left hand side equals to right hand side. How?

60           =             3(17) + 9   <== if you multiply 3 by 17 you get 51 then plus 9, that is 60. Which means both sides are now equal.

Step 5: – Now take 17 to your left hand side and 9 to your right hand side.

17           =             9

Step 6:- ask how many times 9 goes to 17. That is 1.8…….

17           =             1(9)

Step 7:- Step 4: – now you need to balance this 17       =             1(9)

17           =             1(9) + 8  <== if you multiply 1 by 9 you get 9 then plus 8, that is 17. Which means both sides are now equal.

Step 8:- again take 9 to your left hand side and 8 to your right hand side.

9              =             1(8)

9              =             1(8) + 1 <== once you reached +1 to balance your equation, you may stop and start doing back substitution.

Step A:-Last equation in step 8 which is    9 = 1(8) + 1    can be written as follows:
1.= 9 – 1(8)

Step B:-We know what is (8) by simple saying 8 = 17 – 1(9) from step 7. Now we can re-write step A as:-

1=9 -1(17 – 1(9)) <== here since 9=1(9) we can re-write as:-

1=1(9)-1(17) +1(9) <== group similar terms. In this case you add 1(9) with 1(9) – that is 2(9).

1=2(9)-1(17)

Step C: – We know what is (9) by simple saying 9 = 60 – 3(17) from step 4. Now we can re-write step B as:-

1=2(60-3(17) -1(17)

1=2(60)-6(17) -1(17) <== group similar terms. In this case you add 6(17) with 1(17) – that is 7(17).

1=2(60)-7(17) <== at this stage we can stop, nothing more to substitute, therefore take the value next 17. That is 7. Subtract it with the totient.

60-7=d

Then therefore the value of d= 53.

Answer (score 3):

The approved answer by [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo) is incorrect as it uses [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) instead of [Carmichael's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) to find `d`. While the original method of RSA key generation uses Euler's function, `d` is typically derived using Carmichael's function instead for reasons I won't get into. The math needed to find the private exponent `d` given `p` `q` and `e` without any fancy notation would be as follows:

`d = e^-1*mod(((p-1)/GCD(p-1,q-1))(q-1))`

Why is this? Because `d` is defined in the relationship

`de = 1*mod(λ(n))`

Where `λ(n)` is Carmichael's function which is

`λ(n)=lcm(p-1,q-1)`

Which can be expanded to

`λ(n)=((p-1)/GCD(p-1,q-1))(q-1)`

So inserting this into the original expression that defines `d` we get

`de = 1*mod(((p-1)/GCD(p-1,q-1))(q-1))`

And just rearrange that to the final formula

`d = e^-1*mod(((p-1)/GCD(p-1,q-1))(q-1))`

More related information can be found [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/calculating-rsa-private-exponent-when-given-public-exponent-and-the-modulus-fact).

Answer (score 2):

I just want to augment the [Sidudozo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310871/in-rsa-encryption-how-do-i-find-d-given-p-q-e-and-c/33426933#33426933) and clarify some important points.

First of all, what should we pass to Extended Euclidean Algorthim to compute `d` ?

Remember that `ed mod φ(n) = 1` and `cgd(e, φ(n)) = 1`.

Knowing that the Extended Euclidean Algorthim is based on the formula `cgd(a,b) = as + bt`, hence `cgd(e, φ(n)) = es + φ(n)t = 1`, where `d` should be equal to `s + φ(n)` in order to satisfy the

`ed mod φ(n) = 1` condition.

So, given the `e=17` and `φ(n)=60` (borrowed from the [Sidudozo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310871/in-rsa-encryption-how-do-i-find-d-given-p-q-e-and-c/33426933#33426933)), we substitute the corresponding values in the formula mentioned above:
`cgd(e, φ(n)) = es + φ(n)t = 1` ⇔ `17s + 60t = 1`.

At the end of the [Sidudozo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310871/in-rsa-encryption-how-do-i-find-d-given-p-q-e-and-c/33426933#33426933) we obtain `s = -7`. Thus `d = s + φ(n)` ⇔ `d = -7 + 60` ⇒ `d = 53`.

Let's verify the results. The condition was `ed mod φ(n) = 1`.

Look  **17 * 53 mod 60 = 1**. Correct!

Comment: Hw do i find t in your equation?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this formula,

d = (1+K(phi))/e. (Very useful when e and phi are small numbers)

Lets say, e = 3 and phi = 40
we assume K = 0, 1, 2... until your d value  is not a decimal

assume K = 0, then
d = (1+0(40))/3 = 0. (if it is a decimal increase the K value, don't bother finding the exact value of the decimal)

assume K = 2, then
d = (1+2(40)/3) = 81/3 = 27

d = 27.

Assuming K will become exponentially easy with practice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for it, in python:

```py
def inverse(a, n):
    t, newt = 0, 1
    r, newr = n, a

    while newr:
        quotient = r // newr  # floor division
        t, newt = newt, t - quotient * newt
        r, newr = newr, r - quotient * newr
    
    if r > 1:
        return None  # there's no solution
    
    if t < 0:
        t = t + n
    
    return t


inverse(17, 60)  # returns 53
```

adapted from pseudocode found in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Taken the values `p=7, q=11` and `e=17`.
then the value of `n=p*q=77` and `f(n)=(p-1)(q-1)=60`.
Therefore, our public key pair is,`(e,n)=(7,77)`
Now for calvulating the value of `d` we have the constraint,

```
e*d == 1 mod (f(n)), [here "==" represents the **congruent symbol**].
17*d == 1 mod 60
(17*53)*d == 53 mod 60, [7*53=901, which gives modulus value 1]
1*d == 53 mod 60
```

hence,this gives the value of `d=53`.
Therefore our private key pair will be, `(d,n)=(53,77)`.

Hope this help. Thank you!